# How to make all tables responsive within DIV

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive-design

This code for overflowing all tables inside `div`s works (responsive on mobile). The caveat is that all `div`s must be inside a table called "maintable".

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    table.maintable td>div {
        padding-left: 0px !important;
        padding-right: 0px !important;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

        .maintable, .maintable tbody, .maintable tbody tr, .maintable tbody tr td
    {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }

    #responsive-tables table {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #responsive-tables tbody tr {
        display: table-row;
    }
    #responsive-tables tbody tr td {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 15px 10px;
        vertical-align: inherit;
        width: -webkit-fill-available;
    }
    #responsive_mobile_outer img {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        max-width: 300px;
    }

}
```

For this page:

```
<table class="maintable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
    <tr>    
        <td>

<div id="responsive-tables"><table class="feestable" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" width="99%">
 ....
</table></div>
```

How do I get rid of "maintable" and make it work for this page?

```
<div class="best">
 <div class="maincell">

<div id="responsive-tables"><table class="feestable" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" width="99%">
 ....
</table></div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "How to get rid of "maintable""?

Comment: I don't want maintable. Instead it I want

<div class="best">
 <div class="maincell">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are clear enough but your question is burdened with unnecessary specifics.  Here is the general principal.  I'll leave it to you to adapt this to your own application.

```css
.table-responsive {
  max-width:100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Column 01</th>
    <th>Column 02</th>
    <th>Column 03</th>
    <th>Column 04</th>
    <th>Column 05</th>
    <th>Column 06</th>
    <th>Column 07</th>
    <th>Column 08</th>
    <th>Column 09</th>
    <th>Column 10</th>
    <th>Column 11</th>
    <th>Column 12</th>
    <th>Column 13</th>
    <th>Column 14</th>
    <th>Column 15</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
    <td>Testing 123...</td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jonattan! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Please upvote/accept to show your appreciation.  That's what keeps this machine running!